# Difference between styles of English in technical communication

Tags: american-english, british-english, word-order, writing-style, adverb-position

I have a collaborative software project with two other users. Nearly every technical report and documentation written goes through the following editorial changes to some of the sentences (examples below; note the differences in the parts in italics):

#### User A (original version)

1. Example X *can also be* written as Y
2. As *is often* the case, ...
3. Such programs *are generally* known as ...

#### User B (revised version)

1. Example X *also can be* written as Y
2. As *often is* the case, ...
3. Such programs *generally are* known as ...

Now both users are native speakers of English. As a non-native myself, I'm confused between the right style here. Both seem correct to me, but I couldn't care less either way. The consistency with which the users write these sentences makes me wonder if it is due to US/UK English conventions. An alternative explanation might be the expected style of writing in technical communication.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Are you asserting that User B is from the UK and A is from the US?

Comment: I (a U.S. speaker) find all three of user A's original versions to be much, much better than user B's revised versions.

Comment: @horatio I'm making no such explicit assertions so as to not prejudice the thought, but yes they're from different regions.

Comment: The 3rd example is fundamentally different: A always means *programs of this type are generally called...*, whereas B can equally mean *programs **of this general type** are called...*

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of technical style.

Comment: I (a British English speaker) find user A's three versions flow better

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers and additional insights. I think JR's hunch is the most likely explanation. I personally always preferred user A's versions (pretty much everyone here does too), but it was good to know that user B's versions aren't wrong... just awkward. JLG's references were also very helpful in confirming this. For now, I must part, but if you liked the question, give everyone who answered a round of upvotes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think any of us can say for sure, but it looks to me like User B is holding fast to the *[**Thou Shalt Not Split Thine Infinitives**](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/split-infinitives.aspx)* commandment (hence, **don't** put an *also* in the middle of the *can be*, and **don't** insert a *generally* inside the *are known*).

As for my personal opinion, I think the versions of User A sound more natural, and User B is sacrificing some measure of readability for the sake of adhering to strict grade-school grammar rules.  If my theory is right, it might be hard for User B to concede that User A has done a better job with the edits.

Comment: Sounds like a good theory to me. By implication, you think User B is a somewhat ignorant pedant - which I agree with, because his choice of word-order is stilted in the first two examples, and ambiguous in the third.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If I had to put money on it, I would likely lay my chips on the _pedantic twit_ theory, not the _from-either-side-of-the-pond_ theory. As I mentioned, though, there's no way to tell for sure based on the limited information provided.

Comment: I answered much the same as this below but deleted because it's too similar. The only thing I wanted to add is that adverb placement in English is flexible, unless it can cause confusion. I wouldn't call User B's choices wrong, but I would call them just what FF said - pedantic.

Comment: This is actually a good theory. I think they're just rigidly sticking to grade school grammar without being aware of it.

Comment: @Marcus_33: That's a good point. I wouldn't call either wording outright _wrong_, it's just that the word orderings proposed by User B don't seem to flow as naturally. (Interesting how no one has chimed in to said that User B has written better than User A.)

Comment: @Marcus_33: But B's choice on #3 **is** "wrong", because his version can have a different meaning. Personally, if I didn't know from OP's context what meaning *was* intended, I would have erroneously understood that different meaning as the intended one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wouldn't you need an additional comma to get to your interpretation of the third example?

Comment: @fsm: Certainly not! You could optionally put commas *before and after* the word "generally" to force my interpretation, but grammatically speaking it's the default interpretation anyway. An adverb or adjective generally modifies the nearest appropriate word, and if both the preceding *and* following word are equally "appropriate" (as here), the default is to apply it to the first suitable candidate.

Comment: User B's edits bring to mind the harridan who somehow, despite a combination of towering ego and epic incompetence, was the editor of one of the tech writing groups in the software development shop where I was an intern. (I was on loan to the _other_ tech writing group, which was mentored by the estimable Prof. Marvin Klotz.)

Comment: J.R., This goes beyond the split infinitive rule, which usually means Thou Shalt Not Split the Infinitive Verb From Its Infinitive Marker; that's not in play in any of these,and only one 1. uses an infinitive. B seems to be erecting a new and even more absurd rule that Thou Shalt Not Split ANY Periphrastic Verbal Construction.

Comment: Pedantic twit - ha ha! Yes, questioning the need for editing, at all. Definitely split these two up and get them to do something useful.

Answer (score 10):

I am in the U.S. and I agree with User A's original versions. In Claire Kehrwald Cook's book *Line By Line* (which I highly recommend), Ms. Cook, writes (p. 23):

> An adverb modifying a verb phrase goes after the first word in the phrase (*was extremely surprised, has often been said, would certainly have asked*) unless, in verb phrases of three or more words, it modifies only the participle (*had been justly accused, would have been officially ruled*). You usually know instinctively when to put the adverb before the participle, and when you can't be sure, the position probably makes no difference.

This passage should address your last two examples. (That is, User A's wording is preferable.)

As for the placement of *also*, Ms. Cook writes (p. 25):

> Whatever the grammatical complexities, *also*—meaning "in addition"—can attach itself to a variety of sentence elements, so that you have to place it carefully to avoid false connections. What element is "in addition" in the following sentence?
>
> > *I also think he is lying about where he was that night.*
>
> Do you give the same answer when you read that sentence as the second of a pair?
>
> > *She doesn't believe the defendant's alibi for the night of the murder. I also think he is lying about where he was that night.*
> >
> > *I think he hated her enough to killer her. I also think he is lying about where he was that night.*
> >
> > *The defendant lied about his pevious marriage. I also think he is lying about where he was that night.*
>
> These examples should demonstrate that *also* in the normal adverbial positions can sometimes seem to modify one sentence element and sometimes another, the interpretation varying with the context. Strictly speaking, the *also* belongs before *think* only  when the sentence states an additional thought, as in the second example. Substituting *too* for *also* would more clearly convey the sense intended in the first example, and in the last example *also* belongs between *is* and *lying.*

In your first example, *Example X can also be written as Y*... is fine and preferable. You're talking about two ways of writing X.

Can you point this pattern of writing and revising out to the two parties involved? It is an astute observation, and they would both benefit from knowing they have a careful collaborator in you. You might recommend *Line by Line*, too.

Answer (score 4):

User A's answers sound better to me. I think you should tell User B to do some constructive work instead of replacing perfectly sound phrases with strange ones.

Comment: Hi Aleksander, welcome to ELU. That's sound advice indeed in your first answer!

Comment: I would agree and say that the editor deals with the grammar and the authors get a veto IIF the meaning is incorrect.